Mesh from Curve: Object origin rotation not aligned with rotation of object
Object origin rotation not aligned with rotation of object after converting curve to mesh. Also see attached .blend file. is this a bug or is there something I'm missing in geometry nodes ?


Exact steps for others to reproduce the error

⇧ Shift + A Add > Curve > Path
Select NurbsPath object just created and go to Geometry Nodes tab.
Hit + button to add a new geometry node setup
Create basic geometry nodes setup to instance a cube along a Nurbspath
Group input > Curve to points > Instance on Points > Realize Instance > Group Output
Cube > Instance on Points
Select NurbsPath in 3D viewport in Object mode and go to Object > Convert > Mesh
Go to Edit mode and Hit A to select all and go to: Mesh > Separate > By Loose Parts
Go To Object mode and go to: Object > Set Origin > Origin to center of mass (volume) or Origin to geometry
8a. Object mode, select the object go to Physics properties panel and add Rigid Body > Collisions > Shape > Box
8b. Object mode, Options and select Origins to view the rotation of the origin ?


Whenever you instance the cubes onto a curve you aren't copying the object each time, with it's own local transforms. Once you convert the curve to mesh and split it into individual parts it will retain the rotation from the curve object it was a part of.

is its possible to get the rotation of each seperate object. Add this into the current geometry nodes setup or maby another setup ? Once i convert curve to mesh i would like to be able to create a rigid body sim with shape box (huge simulation) with the objects created by geo nodes. For that i need correct rotation so i can use box instead of Convex Hull. Rerotate individual objects is not a option because there are thousands. How would i achieve this ?

use another method like array a plane, activate its Object > Instancing > Faces, parent the cube to the plane, there will be one instance of cube per face?

Yes this is a possibility maby. But i would like to use a Curve so i can "draw" a line (Curve) and then the objects are placed based on that Curve. So basicly what im trying to do is an easy whay to "draw" objects in place and then create a rigid body simulation.
